# Getting the first image elements id within an unordered list using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the id of the first element of an unordered list using JQuery.

Here's the list

```
<ul class="list">
<li><img id="1" src="image1.jpg" name="image1" /></li>
<li><img id="2" src="image2.jpg" name="image2" /></li>
<li><img id="3" src="image3.jpg" name="image3" /></li>
<li><img id="4" src="image4.jpg" name="image4" /></li>
<li><img id="5" src="image5.jpg" name="image5" /></li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
var id = $('.list li img'):first.attr('id');
```

Comment: No, you don't. You seem to want the `id` of the first element within the first element of an unordered list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close.

```
var id = $('.list li img:first').attr('id');
```